# $f$ is bounded in probability iff $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Prove that $f$ is bounded in probability iff $f$ is finite a.e.

We say that $f$ bounded in probability if given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite real number $M_{\epsilon}$ such that $m(\{|f| \leq M_{\epsilon}\}) \geq 1 - \epsilon$.

- $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I'm trying to prove the first implication. My approach is take $\{|f| = \infty\}$ and show that $m(\{|f| = \infty\}) = 0$, but, I don't know how to use the hypothesis with this ideia. Maybe, there is a some simpler way. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** For each $M>0$ we have 
$$m(\{ |f| =\infty\}) \leq m(\{ |f| >M \})$$

Comment: I apologize, but I don't see the connection. How I use the hint with $m(\{|f| \leq M_{\epsilon}\}) \leq 1 - \epsilon$? I think that I should to do $\epsilon$  grow up for $m(\{|f| \leq M_{\epsilon}\}) \leq 0$, but I don't know how I would use this with the hint.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa $ m(\{ |f| >M \})=1- m(\{ |f| \leq M \})$. You can make the RHS as small as you want.

Comment: Of course! I forgot this property, thank you!